# django migrate has error: Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I change my model field from Charfiled() to GenericIPAddressField()

```
ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
```

and use django 1.7 migrate

```
./manage.py makemigrations core
./manage.py migrate
```

But there is error:

```
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "ip" cannot be cast automatically to type inet
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
```

I try this,but not work:

```
ALTER TABLE core_message ALTER COLUMN ip TYPE inet USING (ip::inet);
```

error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type inet: ""
```

What can I do now?
Please help me Thank you!

Comment: Your `ip` column is currently `text` or `varchar`, right? The error message indicates that you have empty strings in `ip` and `''::inet` won't work. You'll need to replace those empty strings with NULLs (`update core_message set ip = null where ip = ''`) before your ALTER TABLE. I don't know the proper Django way to do any of that though.

Answer (score 9):

one quick fix will be to drop and create the field:

1. delete the migration what is changing the field type.
2. delete/comment the field `ip`
3. make migrations
4. get back/uncomment the field `ip` with the new field type
5. make migrations
6. migrate

I did this in production and restored the data with a previous csv backup and an python script of a few lines a code.